# Atom Editor and Discord with Python, Getting error discord.ext.commands.errors.NoEntryPointError: Extension

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, atom-editor

on main code lines 15-21

```py
@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```

on rs9.py in Cog: lines 1-9 Below.

```py
import discord
import os
import random
from discord.ext import commands

class rs9(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self,client):
        self.client=client
```

I have the same exact format typed out  for an eightball command in another cog that works fine. for some reason this cog keeps throwing the codes:

Set up Block:

```py
        def setup(client):
            client.add_cog(rs9(client))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 613, in _load_from_module_spec
    setup = getattr(lib, 'setup')
AttributeError: module 'cogs.rs9' has no attribute 'setup'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\Discordbot\Seymour.py", line 21, in <module>
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
  File "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 664, in load_extension
    self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 616, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.NoEntryPointError(key)
discord.ext.commands.errors.NoEntryPointError: Extension 'cogs.rs9' has no 'setup' function.
[Finished in 0.45s]
```

THank you for any help on this matter.

Comment: While The answer itself is good, I would recommend to change the title so that reflects more what you are asking and what the main topic is, but in a way. For instance. Atom Editor and Discord, Getting  discord.ext.commands.errors.NoEntryPointError: Extension

Comment: Have a look here => [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

Answer (score 0):

In the `cogs.rs9` file the setup function should be unindented

```py
import discord
import os
import random
from discord.ext import commands

class rs9(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    # Put the commands here


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(rs9(client))
```